# Nonempty set and bounded from below

Tags: real-analysis

I have this set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}, f(x)>y\}$, where f is defined by: 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x+1; x<-1\\ 0, -1\leq x\leq 1\\x-1; 1<x\end{cases}$$

I draw f but I don't know how to see from the graph ?

thank you

Comment: Should it be $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x) > x\}$? $y$ is never defined.

Comment: no it is written like this, they defined the function g by $g(y)=\inf\{x\in R, f(x)>y\}$ they ask to prove that g is well defined,

Comment: @nbritten I think that the y it represent the ordinate

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$ be given. If $y < 0$, then $f(0) = 0 > y$. If $0\leq y \leq 1$, then $f(2) = 3 > y$. If $y > 1$, then $f(y) = y + 1 > y$. So in all cases $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x) > y\}$ is nonempty.

Note that $f(x) \leq x + 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (this is also checked by cases). So $f(x) > y$ implies $x + 1 \geq f(x) > y$. Thus $x > y - 1$, and $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x) > y\}$ is bounded below by $y - 1$ for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Any nonempty set of real numbers bounded below has a unique infinimum, so $g$ is well defined.

Comment: can you explain me how to get the idea please

Comment: For $f(x) \geq x - 1$? If $x < -1$, then $f(x) = x - 1 \geq x - 1$. So the bound holds for $x  < -1$. Make similar arguments for $ -1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $x> 1$.

Comment: but to say that the set is bounded from below we must have that there exists $m\in R$, for all $x\in \{ x\in R, f(x)>y\}$, $x\geq m$

Comment: $y$ is fixed when we're looking for the inf, so $y - 1$ is the required $M$.

Comment: how you get y-1 @?

Comment: Edited to include more details.

Comment: I don't understand  one time you say f(x)<x+1 and an other f(x)>x-1

Comment: Well they're both true, assuming you include the possibility of equality. I thought this argument might be easier to follow.